# Laravel Query Builder Mysql Query Double Case Then Else Statement

Tags: mysql

Could anyone help me with this query?

```
DB::raw('(CASE WHEN lime_survey_921959.921959X45X591 IS NOT NULL
          THEN (CASE WHEN lime_survey_921959.921959X45X590 = "AO01" 
          THEN "YES" ELSE "NO" END) ELSE "YES" END) AS HasActivity')
```

When the field is Null, the result is correct the query returns "YES", When the field is not Null and the result is "AO01" it also returns "YES". But when the field is not Null, and the result is different from "AO01" it continues to return "YES" when I need it to return "NO".

Try replace CASE, ELSE, THEN position, but ever returns an error

Answer (score 0):

If the field is not NULL and the response differs from "AO01," and you want to return "NO," you can use a more straightforward query.

```
DB::raw('CASE 
    WHEN lime_survey_921959.921959X45X591 IS NULL THEN "YES"
    WHEN lime_survey_921959.921959X45X591 != "AO01" THEN "NO"
    ELSE "YES"
END AS HasActivity')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. Unfortunately it still hasn't worked. The field is not Null and the response is different from "AO01", but it continues to return "YES"

Comment: I updated my answer, please see if it works.